# Why a explizit serialization of Json objects?

Tags: angular, typescript

There are many methodes to make a typescrpt class out of a json response.

in many projects I did it like this :

```
export class Group
{
  constructor(
    public Id?: number,
    public Name?: string,
    public Users?: User[],
    public Role?: Role,
    public Customers: Customer[] = new Array())
  {
  }
}
```

The main benefit is that it is simple and clean, but there is no software which can automatically convert a c# class to this.

Then I digged and found https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio
this can convert c# models classes to typescript.

**Q : Why should I serialize each JSON like this `Language.fromJS(requestJson)` ?**

I can see no risk to go with my old method in the future.

```
export class Language {
    id: number;
    flag?: string | null;

    init(data?: any) {
        if (data) {
            this.id = data["Id"] !== undefined ? data["Id"] : <any>null;
            this.flag = data["Flag"] !== undefined ? data["Flag"] : <any>null;
        }
    }

    static fromJS(data: any): Language {
        let result = new Language();
        result.init(data);
        return result;
    }

    toJSON(data?: any) {
        data = typeof data === 'object' ? data : {};
        data["Id"] = this.id !== undefined ? this.id : <any>null;
        data["Flag"] = this.flag !== undefined ? this.flag : <any>null;
        return data; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your first option is that you have to provide the properties  every time you want an instance from a JSON response:

```
new Group(json.id, json.name, ...)
```

Whereas with your second option you can abstract the JSON-to-instance conversion in a single place -- the `fromJS` method. And with the explicit `toJSON` method you can control the structure of the object when it gets serialized -- this may be helpful when you need the same property to be named something in TypeScript and something else in your server-side.

Comment: not correct, i dont have to provide the properties that happens automatically

Comment: How does that happen automatically? How are you creating an instance with your first option?

Comment: oh wait you are right im not creating an instance im fake casting it  <myobject[]>response.json(), ty